# How to send different amounts of data through pipes and measure the execution time between them?

Tags: c, linux, process, pipe

I'm currently trying to send large and different amounts of data through pipes in Linux between a parent and a child process.

The amounts of data that I'm sending are: 1 KB, 10 KB, 100 KB, 1 MB, 10 MB and 100 MB.

The problem is that, although the packets are getting bigger and bigger, the execution times in each case are very similar, when in fact they should be increasing.

Here is the code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

char* generateData(int kbNum) {
    int bytes = 1024 * kbNum;
    char* data = malloc(bytes);

    for (int i = 0; i<bytes; i++) data[i] = '*';

    return data;
}

void errorMessage(const char *message){
    printf("%s",message);
    exit(1);
}

void printTimes(long int* times){
    int fileSize = 1;
    bool bigger = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        if (bigger) printf("El tiempo para %dMB fue de %ld μs usando tuberias\n", fileSize, times[i]);
        else printf("El tiempo para %dKB fue de %ld μs usando tuberias\n", fileSize, times[i]);

        if (fileSize < 100) fileSize = fileSize * 10;
        else {
            fileSize = 1;
            bigger = true;
        }
    }
}

void checkErrors(int processId, int pipesPointers[2]){
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++){
        if (pipesPointers[i] < 0){
            // Generating the corresponding error message for pipe error
            char message[] = "Error starting the pipe ";
            strcat(message, (char*) &i);
            errorMessage(message);
        }
    }

    // Generating the corresponding error message for the fork
    if (processId < 0) errorMessage("Error generating the fork");
}

void childrenProcess(int pipeWrite, int pipeRead){
    int check = 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100001; i = i * 10){
        char* data = malloc(1024 * i);

        // Get Data Package
        read(pipeRead, &data, sizeof(data));

        // Sending check
        write(pipeWrite, &check, sizeof(int));
    }
}

void parentProcess(int pipeWrite, int pipeRead){
    struct timeval start, stop;
    long int times[6];
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 100001; i = i * 10){
        char* data = generateData(i);
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
        int dataCheck;

        // Sending Data Package to consumer
        write(pipeWrite, &data, sizeof(data));

        // Getting the check confirmation 
        read(pipeRead, &dataCheck, sizeof(dataCheck));

        // Get the time elapsed time
        gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);

        times[index] = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000 + stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;
        index++;
        free(data);
    }

    printTimes(times);
}

void startProgram(){
    int pipePointers[2], parentPipes[2], childrenPipes[2];
    pid_t processId = 0;

    // Creating emparented processes and pipes
    pipePointers[0] = pipe(parentPipes);
    pipePointers[1] = pipe(childrenPipes);
    processId = fork();
    checkErrors(processId, pipePointers);

    // Spliting the code that witch process will execute
    if (processId == 0){
        close(childrenPipes[0]);
        close(parentPipes[1]);
        childrenProcess(childrenPipes[1], parentPipes[0]);
        close(childrenPipes[1]);
        close(parentPipes[0]);
    }
    else if (processId > 0){
        close(childrenPipes[1]);
        close(parentPipes[0]);
        parentProcess(parentPipes[1], childrenPipes[0]);
        close(childrenPipes[0]);
        close(parentPipes[1]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
    startProgram();
    return 0;
}
```

And here are the output times:

```
The elapsed time for 1KB was 41 μs using pipes.
The elapsed time for 10KB was 88 μs using pipes.
The elapsed time for 100KB was 74 μs using pipes.
The elapsed time for 1MB was 79 μs using pipes.
The elapsed time for 10MB was 34 μs using pipes.
The elapsed time for 100MB was 24 μs using pipes.
```

I would be very grateful for your help, I will be attentive to any comments or answers.

For everything else, have a wonderful day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the child process, you have:

```
read(pipeRead, &data, sizeof(data));
```

Where you have `char *data = …`.  Similarly in the parent with the `write()`.  This means you are writing 8 bytes (assuming a 64-bit CPU) to the child and the size doesn't change so neither does the time.

To fix, you need to calculate the size of the data to be sent in a variable and use that in the calls to `read()` and `write()`.  You also should be passing just `data` and not `&data` to both `read()` and `write()`.

There are other problems — one of the bigger ones is the loop in the child `for (int i = 0; i < 100001; i = i * 10){`.  Zero times ten is still zero, so the loop runs for a long time.  Another problem is that you need to read all the data that's written, but there is a finite size for the pipe buffer (usually 64 KiB on modern systems; it used to be 5 KiB on old systems).  I worked around this with the functions `multi_read()` and `multi_write()`.  I also made the error message code more flexible.  I made some names more consistent.  It ends up with code such as this:

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

static void errorMessage(const char *message, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, message);
    vfprintf(stderr, message, args);
    va_end(args);
    exit(1);
}

static char *generateData(int kbNum)
{
    int bytes = 1024 * kbNum;
    char *data = malloc(bytes);

    if (data == NULL)
        errorMessage("failed to allocate %d bytes of memory\n", bytes);

    memset(data, '*', bytes);

    return data;
}

static void printTimes(long int *times)
{
    int fileSize = 1;
    bool bigger = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        if (bigger)
            printf("El tiempo para %dMB fue de %ld μs usando tuberias\n", fileSize, times[i]);
        else
            printf("El tiempo para %dKB fue de %ld μs usando tuberias\n", fileSize, times[i]);

        if (fileSize < 100)
            fileSize = fileSize * 10;
        else
        {
            fileSize = 1;
            bigger = true;
        }
    }
}

static void checkErrors(int processId, int pipesPointers[2])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        if (pipesPointers[i] < 0)
        {
            // Generating the corresponding error message for pipe error
            char message[] = "Error starting the pipe ";
            strcat(message, (char *)&i);
            errorMessage(message);
        }
    }

    // Generating the corresponding error message for the fork
    if (processId < 0)
        errorMessage("Error generating the fork");
}

static ssize_t multi_read(int fd, char *buffer, size_t nbytes)
{
    ssize_t nb = 0;
    size_t nleft = nbytes;
    ssize_t tbytes = 0;
    while (nleft > 0 && (nb = read(fd, buffer, nleft)) > 0)
    {
        tbytes += nb;
        buffer += nb;
        nleft  -= nb;
    }
    if (tbytes == 0)
        tbytes = nb;
    return tbytes;
}

static ssize_t multi_write(int fd, const char *buffer, size_t nbytes)
{
    ssize_t nb = 0;
    size_t nleft = nbytes;
    ssize_t tbytes = 0;
    while (nleft > 0 && (nb = write(fd, buffer, nleft)) > 0)
    {
        tbytes += nb;
        buffer += nb;
        nleft  -= nb;
    }
    if (tbytes == 0)
        tbytes = nb;
    return tbytes;
}

static void childProcess(int pipeWrite, int pipeRead)
{
    int check = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i < 100001; i = i * 10)     // i = 1 is key!
    {
        size_t size = 1024 * i;
        char *data = malloc(size);

        if (data == NULL)
            errorMessage("failed to allocate memory\n");

        printf("Child reading %zu bytes of data\n", size);

        // Get Data Package
        if (multi_read(pipeRead, data, size) != (ssize_t)size)
            errorMessage("Read error in %s()\n", __func__);

        // Sending check
        if (write(pipeWrite, &check, sizeof(check)) != sizeof(check))
            errorMessage("Write error in %s()\n", __func__);
    }
}

static void parentProcess(int pipeWrite, int pipeRead)
{
    struct timeval start, stop;
    long int times[6];
    int index = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < 100001; i = i * 10)
    {
        size_t size = 1024 * i;
        char *data = generateData(i);
        printf("Parent writing %zu bytes of data\n", size);
        gettimeofday(&start, NULL);
        int check;

        // Sending Data Package to consumer
        if (multi_write(pipeWrite, data, size) != (ssize_t)size)
            errorMessage("Write error in %s()\n", __func__);

        // Getting the check confirmation
        if (read(pipeRead, &check, sizeof(check)) != sizeof(check))
            errorMessage("Read error in %s()\n", __func__);

        // Get the time elapsed time
        gettimeofday(&stop, NULL);

        times[index] = (stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * 1000000 + stop.tv_usec - start.tv_usec;
        index++;
        free(data);
    }

    printTimes(times);
}

static void startProgram(void)
{
    int pipePointers[2], parentPipes[2], childrenPipes[2];
    pid_t processId = 0;

    // Creating emparented processes and pipes
    pipePointers[0] = pipe(parentPipes);
    pipePointers[1] = pipe(childrenPipes);
    processId = fork();
    checkErrors(processId, pipePointers);

    // Spliting the code that witch process will execute
    if (processId == 0)
    {
        close(childrenPipes[0]);
        close(parentPipes[1]);
        childProcess(childrenPipes[1], parentPipes[0]);
        close(childrenPipes[1]);
        close(parentPipes[0]);
    }
    else if (processId > 0)
    {
        close(childrenPipes[1]);
        close(parentPipes[0]);
        parentProcess(parentPipes[1], childrenPipes[0]);
        close(childrenPipes[0]);
        close(parentPipes[1]);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    startProgram();
    return 0;
}
```

A sample run gives:

```
Parent writing 1024 bytes of data
Child reading 1024 bytes of data
Child reading 10240 bytes of data
Parent writing 10240 bytes of data
Child reading 102400 bytes of data
Parent writing 102400 bytes of data
Child reading 1024000 bytes of data
Parent writing 1024000 bytes of data
Child reading 10240000 bytes of data
Parent writing 10240000 bytes of data
Child reading 102400000 bytes of data
Parent writing 102400000 bytes of data
El tiempo para 1KB fue de 312 μs usando tuberias
El tiempo para 10KB fue de 269 μs usando tuberias
El tiempo para 100KB fue de 324 μs usando tuberias
El tiempo para 1MB fue de 1042 μs usando tuberias
El tiempo para 10MB fue de 8136 μs usando tuberias
El tiempo para 100MB fue de 77713 μs usando tuberias
```

Comment: OMG, how could I miss that ‍♀️. Thank you so much for your help, you really saved me from a headache for trying to solve this. I wish you a wonderful day today!