# `read()` multiple times, or at once in network programming?

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming

What's the better practice for using the c language `read()` function in network programming?

Some programs reads the first header byte, and reads additional bytes in each case.
Some programs read the total size of the buffer and passes the buffer pointer.

1. Read the first header byte, and read additional bytes in each case.

```
int main(){
   unsigned char buffer[MAX_SIZE];
   read(socket, buffer, 1);
   switch(buffer[0]) {
       case MSG_TYPE_1:
           handle_1(socket);
           break;
       case MSG_TYPE_2:
           handle_2(socket);
           break;
   }
}
void handle_1(int socket){
   unsigned char buffer[8];
   unsigned int length = read(socket, buffer, 8);
   /// handle buffer ...
}
void handle_2(int socket){
   unsigned char buffer[24];
   unsigned int length = read(socket, buffer, 24);
   /// handle buffer ...
}
```

2. Read maximum byte of the buffer size, and pass the buffer pointer to each handling functions.

```
main(){
   unsigned char buffer[MAX_SIZE];
   unsigned int length = read(socket, buffer, MAX_SIZE);
   switch(buffer[0]) {
       case MSG_TYPE_1:
           handle_1(buffer, length);
           break;
       case MSG_TYPE_2:
           handle_2(buffer, length);
           break;
   }
}
void handle_1(unsigned char *buffer, unsigned int length){
   /// handle buffer ...
   }
}
```

What's a more standard way?

I see that the first case reads specific bytes of each cases. I get another question here:
What is the overhead of requesting read() more bytes than actually received bytes?

For example, actual sent bytes from the other side is 10 bytes, but I `read(socket, buffer, 100);`
I know that the return value of the `read()` will be 10, but is there an overhead?

Comment: `read()` is a system call, and the fewer system calls the better. Read the buffer and pass it around, along with its length.

Comment: 'What is the overhead of requesting read() more bytes than actually received bytes?': zero. It will block while no data is available, then return what data is available up to the length requested. There is no overhead.

Comment: Note that definitions such as `main(){ … }` only comply with the C90 standard. You should be learning at least C99 and preferably C11 or C18 (none of which allow that).  You should specify the return type — `int main(void) { … }` when you don't use the command line arguments.  Similar comments apply tor the `handle_N()` functions (noting that you can't define `handle_1()` twice in a single TU (translation unit — a source file and the files included directly or indirectly by it).  You are required to specify the return type for all functions, and should declare them before you use them.

Comment: As to the question about reading, if you know the amount of data to expect, read that much data, but capture the return value from `read()`.  If you've not received all the data yet, loop to read the rest.  If the reading fails, then the connection was probably truncated, or the two ends are out of sync.  See the functions `multi_read()` and `multi_write()` in my answer to [How to send different amounts of data through pipes and measure the execution time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68878013/15168)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, none of that is good practice, since it won't work. You are not looking at and using the return value of `read()`. A very important behavior of `read()` is that it will return what is immediately available, which may be less than what you asked for, if it is anything other than a regular file. It will always wait for at least one byte (assuming at least one byte was requested, and non-blocking was not explicitly requested), so that you know you got to the end and no more data can be delivered if it returns zero bytes. However, when you ask for eight bytes, it might return five. If you don't deal with that, your program won't work.

Comment: I agree that it was quite confusing, not saving the return values of `read()`. I edited it. Then what do you think is a good practice?

Comment: Mark Adler, "It will always wait for at least one byte" --Sure about that?

Comment: Umm.... I get that your pointing that it's a blocking function. So you mean there's a risk of blocking forever, so it's better to read only once. Am I right? Just want to be sure of your point. @chux-ReinstateMonica

Comment: @Jake I would expect `read(socket, buffer, MAX_SIZE)` to read 0 to `MAX_SIZE` bytes, not "at least one byte". I am not suggesting it's better to read only once, just commenting that a read of 0 bytes is possible.  A call like `read(socket, buffer, 1);` that your codes has is weak as code is not checking the return value.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica So long as you're not _asking_ for zero bytes and `O_NONBLOCK` was not requested (by default it is not), then yes. From https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/read.html : "When attempting to read from an empty pipe or FIFO: ... If some process has the pipe open for writing and O_NONBLOCK is clear, read() shall block the calling thread until some data is written or the pipe is closed by all processes that had the pipe open for writing."

Comment: @MarkAdler What happens if code is asking for more than zero bytes and `O_NONBLOCK` was not requested _and_ "If some process has the pipe open for writing" is false?  Can read zero bytes be read?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica No, of course not. If there is no one out there to write anything, that's the same as EOF on a file. The point is that `read()` _will_ normally block for at least one byte.

Comment: @MarkAdler So "It will always wait for at least one byte" is more like "It will normally wait for at least one byte"?

Comment: A problem with "It will always wait for at least one byte" is that it supports OP's code of `read(socket, buffer, 1);` without an return value check.  As the pipe writing may not be open yet or some other error occurs, better code would check the return value of `read(... buffer ...)`  before using `buffer[0]`.  Other than that, a very good answer.

Comment: No, even if "always" is absolutely always, it still will return zero on EOF, which _must_ be checked for. As I said, the purpose of `read()` blocking is so that you can _tell_ you're at EOF (or an error) by zero being returned. The whole point of my answer is that the return value of `read()` must always be checked.

Comment: And not only checked but checked for three different conditions, which implies that you must store it into a variable.